# Storing user input from text field into an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays

I am trying to store user input text (in this case a book title) into an array so that I can output it in a table view in another xib.

I'm getting stuck trying to store the "bookTitle.text" info into my "userinfoArray". I know it probably has a simple solution and I know how to do it in C++ but not in Objective-C.  Any tips, links etc. would be great.

Comment: Regarding your tags: Xcode is just an IDE. If your question is not about Xcode itself (e.g. how to create a new file in Xcode) you should not use that tag. In your case Xcode is just the tool you use to write the code. It is not relevant for your question, similar to your fingers and your office chair. You wouldn't tag that question with `fingers` and `chair`, would you? ;-) And welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the heads up. Tags adjusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *userinfoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[bookTitle text]];
[userinfoArray addObject:tempString];
```

you can then access it later with:

```
[userinfoArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

NSMutableArray is very flexible. with addObject:object you can add as many things as you want, remove them with removeObjectAtIndex:index.

more here: [NSMutableArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

alternatively if you know what size your array will have you can use a normal NSArray: [NSArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) which will work similar

sebastian

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
userinfoArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[bookTitle text]];
```

Or if you want to create a longer array with more objetcs then

```
userinfoArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[bookTitle text], secondObject, thirdObject, nil];
```

If you want to add or remove objects later then you may want to use NSMutableArray instead.

If this does not answer your question, then please try to be a bit more specific about your problem.